# Como fazer para passar x segundos e realizar a ação em si

Tags: java

Tenho uma dúvida em Java. Basicamente, eu queria fazer com que um fillrect se desenhasse de 0.5 em 0.5 segundos, mais ou menos desta forma:

```
            if(passedTime >= 0 && passedTime < 500) {
                g.fillRect(0, 45, 64, 64);
            }

            if(passedTime == 500 && passedTime < 1000) {
                g.fillRect(0, 35, 64, 64);
            }
            if(passedTime == 1000 && passedTime < 1500) {
                g.fillRect(0, 25, 64, 64);
            }
            if(passedTime == 1500 && passedTime < 2000) {
                g.fillRect(0, 15, 64, 64);
            }
            if(passedTime >= 2000) {
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
            }
```

sendo que passedTime seria:

```
long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long passedTime = endTime - initTime;
```

Eu queria precisamente que até aos 500 milissegundos (0.5 segundos) ele fizesse esse fillRect , depois dos 500 até aos 1000 fizesse o outro, e sempre assim até aos 2 segundos. Sou novo no java e gostaria de saber o que tenho de fazer e em que medida está errado o que fiz. Obrigado

Comment: `Thread.sleep(500)`